# Prevent closing the Application by Taskmanager (or something similar)

Tags: c#, c++, taskmanager

I'm coding an AntiCheat Module for an own little Projekt. It's coded in C#, but it wouldn't matter, if the solution is in C++ (As long, as it's working).

The Problem is, my program runs in the Background, you can't see it. For that I used this Code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

const int SW_HIDE = 0;
const int SW_SHOW = 5;
var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);
```

But what is, if the User is detecting this program and simply close it? All I need is an Event, that appears when a User is closing it via Taskmanager (or something similar), that the Game can be closed and no cheats can apply & take effect to the game.

Do you have any plan? Or just something what matches my requirements, so that the AntiCheat is working?

As I said, if it's in C++, it doesn't matter.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx

Comment: You should answer to WM_CLOSE or WM_ENDSESSION gracefully. That's the intended way.

Comment: Could you explain it a bit more, Marco?

Comment: I think Marco means that your anti-cheat program should handle these messages and forcefully close the game as well (I'm assuming you can't change the game's code).

Comment: Normal virus (and anti-virus) strategy against forceful termination is to run two processes monitoring each other. If one dies, the other detects this and launches a new copy of the partner process.

Comment: @arunasr Ah, so I should duplicate my project. I check every 20ms, if the other process is running, if not, it starts it again, right?

Comment: @JanKurtGrimm Duplicate project? Hardly... Can be same executable, two (or more) processes started from the same file. Can be different files, if you wish. The first process can exec the other(-s) and monitor that PID is alive. Alternatively, use WIN32 API `CreateProcessEx`. You can monitor the PID, or have a pipe between the processes and detect when the pipe is broken.

Comment: I think it's not the best way, but I like this way to do. I'll try it out. Till now, it's working. If I try to close Process1, Process2 notices that and restarts the first. Thank you! :)